# Cambria fonts not working

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am experiencing the same problem with MikTeX 2.9 as I have with Overleaf, both using XeLaTeX. I need to use CAMBRIA.TTC fonts. The following example formats in both settings without bold and italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CAMBRIA.TTC}
 \begin{document}
 \textsc{Small caps work,} but \textbf{boldface} and \textit{italics} do not work.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont={CAMBRIAB.ttf},ItalicFont={CAMBRIAI.ttf}]{CAMBRIA.TTC}`. Or use simply `\setmainfont{Cambria}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that now all `\textsc`, `\textbf` and `\textit` work correctly with Cambria font.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{Cambria}
 \begin{document}
 \textsc{Small caps work,} but \textbf{boldface} and \textit{italics} do not work.
 \end{document}
```