# Set main font as "Cambria" in Overleaf

Tags: fonts, fontsize

When compiliing with `LuaLaTex`, the [font type `Arial`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) works:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I use [`CAMBRIA.TTC`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507736/cambria-fonts-not-working) it does not work:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CAMBRIA.TTC}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The compilation fails also with the following variation in the code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{Cambria}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

An error says `Package fontspec Error: The font "CAMBRIA" cannot be found.`, but how to get it in Overleaf?

**What is the correct way to use `Cambria` in Overleaf?**

Comment: Just for information, I have tried also ```\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}``` and it does not work either (I get an error saying ```Package fontspec Error: The font "Calibri" cannot be found.```)

Comment: Cambria is not licenced for use on linux systsems, you can use the chromeos cambria compatible font Caladea

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Thanks to your input, I found ```The Cambria clone called Caladea and the Calibri clone is called Carlito. Both can be loaded with fontspec and compiled using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.``` from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653270/how-can-i-select-cambria-or-calibri-fonts-in-overleaf-for-greek-language

Comment: As of my knowledge, both `Calibri` and `Cambria` are the Windows fonts, which `OS` you are using

Comment: @MadyYuvi the OP said overleaf, which is linux

Comment: Overleaf (online editor), but the computer I am using to make this test has Windows...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I missed to look the word `Overleaf`, please excuse

Comment: @Ommo Overleaf can not access your local system so the OS of you computer has no effect here. They use a linux tex.

Comment: Ah, good to know! I did not know about it, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overleaf have the Chrome OS Core fonts installed which include the Cambria compatible Caladea.  The Cambria font distributed with windows is only licenced for use on Windows.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Caladea}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

works on overleaf with lualatex or xelatex

[image]

Comment: Great! Many thanks @David Carlisle!